# How to send data from web to api?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Sorry for question but I don't understand that.

I have this:

```
<a @click.prevent="Submit(0)" href="#">NO</a>
<a @click.prevent="Submit(1)" href="#">OK</a>
```

Now in my vue method submit I want to post value 0 or 1 to my api and then store it in database. I have controller UserVote and model Vote. I am green here.

How my link should do? Where I post that? How I can upload that to db? I need just know, then I will be know everything.

Comment: There is an assumption that when you come to Stackoverflow to ask a question, you have already done some research on your own and that research has led you to writing some code but you having difficulties getting the code to work.  I suspect this question will be closed as "Too Broad".  To prevent this, please include the code you're using to attempt to send the data to the API as well as the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in VueJS that does a API request to some endpoint in your Laravel application. Just send the data to your endpoint and let the PHP controller handle the transmitting to the database.